# Macro operator children are not called from python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator, development

The Macro operator in the following code calls two other operators that log the calls of their invoke and execute functions. If the macro operator is called from the `spacebar` menu, the console output is what is expected:

```
TestOp1.invoke
TestOp1.execute
TestOp2.invoke
TestOp2.execute
```

However, if `TestMacro` is called from a python context (a script / addon / interpreter window), it returns `{'FINISHED'}` without calling the children operators `TestOp1` and `TestOp2`.

What is the proper way to register a Macro operator ?

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Macro, Operator
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class

bl_info = {
    'name': "Test macros",
}


class TestOp1(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'wm.test_op1'
    bl_label = 'Test Op1'

    def execute(self, context):
        print('TestOp1.execute')
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print('TestOp1.invoke')
        return self.execute(context)


class TestOp2(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'wm.test_op2'
    bl_label = 'Test Op2'

    def execute(self, context):
        print('TestOp2.execute\n')
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print('TestOp2.invoke')
        return self.execute(context)


class TestMacro(Macro):
    bl_idname = 'wm.test_macro'
    bl_label = 'Test Macro'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


def register():
    register_class(TestOp1)
    register_class(TestOp2)
    register_class(TestMacro)

    TestMacro.define(TestOp1.bl_idname)
    TestMacro.define(TestOp2.bl_idname)


def unregister():
    unregister_class(TestOp1)
    unregister_class(TestOp2)
    unregister_class(TestMacro)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()

    # This doesnt call TestOp1 or TestOp2
    bpy.ops.wm.test_macro('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Answer (score 3):

The children operators need to be registered with their fully qualified internal name:

```
TestMacro.define('WM_OT_test_op1')
TestMacro.define('WM_OT_test_op2')
```

Comment: Good find...  `TestMacro.define(bpy.ops.wm.test_op1.idname())`

Comment: Doesn't work within the `def register()` function. At that point the Operators are not registered under `bpy.ops` yet:


    `AttributeError: 'BPyOpsSubModOp' object has no attribute 'test_op1'`